# dll + boost + VS2015 + WinXP == crashes

Tags: c++, boost, dll, visual-studio-2015, crash

I'm writing *my.dll* which to be run on *WinXP*, it's compiled with '*vs2015*' and uses '*boost 1.64.0 32bit prebuilt library*'.

There's only one line of code for *my.dll*:

```
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>
```

Try to load it via regsvr32 on WinXP (regsvr32 calls LoadLibrary):

```
regsvr32 my.dll
```

It fails to load, from windbg I see there's an Access violation - code c0000005

I tried the old version 1.63, same problem. I guess it's related to magic statics of vs2015, tried to add the compile flag "/Zc:threadSafeInit-" to disable it but still no luck.

There seems to be compile flags like `BOOST_LOG_USE_COMPILER_TLS`, `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_THREAD_KEYWORD_EXTENSION` for disabling thread-safe for some particular library, but I don't see any flag that can do that for Boost.Thread.

Any idea?

My dev environment is: Win10 + VS2015(update 3) + boost_1.64.0_msvc14_32bit (prebuilt windows binary) + compile flag( "/MT /Zc:threadSafeInit-" )

The testing environment:
   crashes on:  WinXP_sp3  / Win2003_R2 
   works fine on: Win7+

Comment: `regsvr32` is **NOT** a magic "make my DLL work" switch. If you don't know what it does, why are you using it? This is cargo-cult programming. `regsvr32` expects that its argument is a DLL that both _needs_ and _supports_ registration. Passing random DLL's can cause a crash. Don't blame the crash on either `regsvr32` or the DLL, the crash is caused by your command line.

Comment: @MSalter, I didn't explain clearly, I don't expect `regsvr32` to fix the problem. I just need a loader.exe to load my.dll, `regsvr32` calls `LoadLibrary` first, so it can be used to test my.dll. And if I write an loader.exe myself with my vs2015, the crash won't happen because the exe initializes the `tls` environment first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution, just add `cxxflags="/Zc:threadSafeInit- "` to build boost, please note there's a tralling space after '-', otherwise it may cause problem.

for example:

```
G:\boost>b2 variant=debug link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared cxxflags="/Zc:threadSafeInit- "
```

And all the libraries should be built with this flag, in VisualStudio:

Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line, add /Zc:threadSafeInit-

for cmake:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /Zc:threadSafeInit-")
```

Comment: You are probably ignoring the bigger problem, targeting XP requires a different toolset.  v140_xp if you use VS2015.  That selection must also be made when you build boost.

Comment: @HansPassant  Thanks, but is it really necessary to build all libraries with v140_xp? I have many experience that I always build those libraries like boost/cryptopp/jsoncpp/protobuf/etc with just v140, and only build the .exe/.dll with v140_xp, it always seems to work fine.